# Gesture detection clash in flutter between bottom navigation bar and slider

Tags: flutter

My requirement is for the bottom navigation bar and slider to seek a video should be closed as reels and shorts have seeking sliders, but when I make it close to the bottom navigation bar it detects both gestures and gets confused about which should app has to detect and get clicks on nav buttons and sometimes it works to seek.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Nav extends StatefulWidget {
  const Nav({super.key});

  @override
  State<Nav> createState() => _NavState();
}

class _NavState extends State<Nav> {
  double _value = 6.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: SliderTheme(
              data: SliderThemeData(
                // here
                thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 0),
                overlayShape: SliderComponentShape.noThumb,
                trackShape: CustomTrackShape(),
              ),
              child: Slider(
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                value: _value,
                onChanged: (double value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _value = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: "Home",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: "home",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: "ome",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTrackShape extends RoundedRectSliderTrackShape {
  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
  }) {
    final trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight;
    final trackLeft = offset.dx;
    final trackTop = offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight!) / 2;
    final trackWidth = parentBox.size.width;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }
}
```